# Create random rectangle on canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to create a random rectangle on my rectangle class.

I have a function `def randomRects(x,y,width,height)`: (x, y) is the top left corner and width must be less than 90, height less than 70.

I understand to create a random rectangle you have to do something like `canvas.create_rectangle(x1,x2,y1,y1)`, but I'm not sure how to do it in this situation. I'm also not sure if width and height should be in parameters or not.

```
import random

class Rectangle:

def __init__(self, height, width):
    self.height = 80
    self.width = 100
 #not sure if above is correct

def randomRects(x,y,width, height):
        w = random.randrange(100)
        h = random.randrange(80) 
        w.create_rectangle(x,y,width,height)
        h.create_rectangle(x,y,width,height)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

class Recta:
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height=80
        self.width=100
    def randomRects(self,canvas):
        w = random.randrange(100)
        h = random.randrange(80)
        canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,h,w,fill='green')

c = Canvas(root)
c.pack()

tes = Recta(10,20)
tes.randomRects(c)

root.mainloop()
```

Of course the init method is a bit stupid, as it takes arguments but doesn't use them. Your code for that method was correct, though.

Comment: no problem :) I had to run it a few times to see it though, because at first the random rectangles were so small I missed them.

Comment: yeah i was just going through that, do you think i should add in a __str__ and __repr__ method ?

Comment: well there are a lot of things you could do, if you want some minimum size you could do `w = random.randrange(60) + 40`, so it would be at least 40 and anything between that and 100. Just build from where you are and play around, find what suits your needs!

Comment: also, if I helped you, you can thank me by setting my answer as correct and upvoting it :) That's how you show love on stack overflow!

Comment: okay I'm going to try add buttons so i can randomly add rectangles. Never done it before but ill try research haha!

Comment: go ahead! Tkinter is fun to build GUIs with, you can do a lot with it, quickly. Enjoy!

Comment: I was wondering how would you make the rectangles appear at random positions and random sizes?

Comment: in `canvas.create_rectangle(xoffset,yoffset,width,height)` the first two arguments, xoffset and yoffset, specify the position on the plane. so you could just create two more variables like `x=random.randrange(200)` and call `canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,w,h)` to make the rectangle appear at random positions.